# Virtual host error with Apache internal server error

Tags: linux, dns, apache-http-server, webserver, virtual-host

I rented this server recently and I'm trying to set it up as a webserver. Apache is working and I tested phpmyadmin and a test.php file using the ip address directly on the web browser gives a message like "it works!".

Then I entered this configuration in my server's /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/myusername/blogsite
    ServerName blog.mydomain.com
    <Directory "/home/myusername/blogsite">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And restarted apache (which started with no warnings, meaning that directory is correct).

And I set the DNS of that domain to my server's IP address, and now I'm getting this error message when I load my subdomain website (error links are modified for anonymity)

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, root@url.to.serverFromProvider.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Apache Server at blog.mydomain.com Port 80

I'm pretty new at setting webservers, and I don't know what to do. Please advise.

If you require any more information please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `apache2.conf`:

1. Make sure that you have uncommented `NameVirtualHost *:80`.
2. Set `LogLevel debug` so that errors are logged.
3. Check where your error log is stored in the `ErrorLog` attribute.

Then check your error log which should contain the reason for the server error.

Also, do you have a reason for the following line in the `<Directory>` tag or did you just copy it from somewhere? Otherwise you could just remove the whole `<Directory>` tag.

```
Require all granted
```

Comment: I removed the directory tag, and the website works, thank you. But it apparently downloads php files rather than executing them. I found somewhere that it has something to do with `NameVirtualHost *:80` that you wrote. But I didn't find that in my apache2.conf. Could you please explain further where to find that to uncomment it?

Comment: NameVirtualHost is giving me a warning:  ... waiting [Sun Jan 19 13:18:21 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts

Comment: If Apache downloads php files instead of running them it is because it doesn't understand the php file type. Usually because php is not installed or improperly configured: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them.

Comment: Regarding the NameVirtualHost warning, do you have the `NameVirtualHost *:80` setting before your `<VirtualHost *:80>` configuration?

Comment: Also, please mark my answer as correct if you think that it answered your question.

Comment: I tried before and after... both gave the same result. And the solution you posted in the link I tried... it doesn't help. Only if I use the a url (www.mydomain.com) and not the IP address... If I use the IP address as URL it works and PHP gets executed.